# Track mouse movements only on X axis for a certain number of pixels (right direction)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, mouse, pyautogui

I want to be able to have my computer detect when I highlight text on my screen (or I guess when I move the mouse a certain distance in the x axis).

I also want my computer to know that I'm holding down a key, this way I do not misfire a bunch of times moving the cursor around.
I'm trying to put this all to an if statement.

I tried to make the mouse move but im unsure how to tell Python to only focus on the x axis and a certain amount of pixels going right before the if statement triggers another action! Please see the ("Do first action"), ("Do second action") , etc

```
savedpos = (pyautogui.position())
while(True):
    
    curpos = (pyautogui.position())
    if savedpos != curpos:
        savedpos = curpos
```

I want to do something like:

```
my_switch=0
global my_switch
my_switch = my_switch % 3
if savedpos != curpos and my_switch == 0:
    print("Do first action")
    my_switch += 1

elif (event.char) == '3' and my_switch == 1:
     print("Do second action")
     my_switch += 1
        
elif (event.char) == '3' and my_switch == 2:
    print("Do third action")
    my_switch += 1
```

I want python to know when I move my mouse right or left in a straight line on x axis if: 1# did the mouse move right a certain number of pixels #2 was something copied to the clipboard?

I tried to make the mouse move but im unsure how to tell Python to only focus on the x axis and a certain amount of pixels going right before the if statement triggers another action! Please see the ("Do first action"), ("Do second action") , etc

Comment: #I want python to know when I move my mouse right or left in a straight line on x axis if: 1# did the mouse move right a certain number of pixels #2 was something copied to the clipboard?


I tried to make the mouse move but im unsure how to tell Python to only focus on the x axis and a certain amount of pixels going right before the if statement triggers another action! Please see the ("Do first action"), ("Do second action") , etc

Comment: It is difficult to debug code we don't see. Please take the [tour] and look into [ask] in the [help] in order to [edit] and update your question to include a [mre]. Also make sure all related tags, like [tag:pyautogui] are set. Your question currently is only marked with [tag:tkinter] and there are some fundamental differences between these libs.